# Error in Custom Lookup Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html

I am struggling to fix the issue in the below look up component.
The issue is, when ever user is searching the Account name in the search box , it seems to be stuck and results in missing some of the key letters.

for example, if we type 'James Anderson'  ----> will appear as 'Jmes Adrsn' ,,, randomly it is happening

Below is the code  :-

HTML -

```
<template>  
<div class='slds-form-element'>  
  <label class='slds-form-element__label' for='combobox-id-2'>{lookupLabel}</label>  
  <div class='slds-form-element__control'>  
    <div class='slds-combobox_container'>  
      <div class='slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open' aria-expanded='true' aria-haspopup='listbox' role='combobox'>  
        <template if:true={selectedValue}>  
        <div data-key='pilldiv' class='slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left-right' role='none'>  
          <span class='slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account slds-combobox__input-entity-icon' title='object'>  
           <div class='slds-icon slds-icon_small' aria-hidden='true'>  
            <lightning-icon icon-name={iconName} size='small'></lightning-icon>  
           </div>  
           <span class='slds-assistive-text'>Record</span>  
          </span>  
          <input type='text' class='slds-input slds-combobox__input slds-combobox__input-value' id='combobox-id-5' aria-controls='listbox-id-5' role='textbox' placeholder='Select an Option' readonly value={selectedValue} />  
          <button class='slds-button slds-button_icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right' onclick={removeRecordOnLookup}  
          title='Remove selected option'>  
           <span class='slds-button__icon' aria-hidden='true' >  
            <lightning-icon icon-name='utility:close'   
             size='xx-Small' class='slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-icon-text-default' aria-hidden='true'></lightning-icon>  
           </span>  
           <span class='slds-assistive-text'>Remove selected record</span>  
          </button>  
         </div>  
        </template>  

        <template if:false={selectedValue}>  
        <div data-key='searchdiv' class='slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right' role='none'>  
          <input type='text' onfocusout={onLeave} value={searchKey} onkeyup={handleKeyChange} onchange={handleKeyChange} class='slds-input slds-combobox__input slds-has-focus' id='combobox-id-2' aria-autocomplete='list' aria-controls='listbox-id-2' role='textbox' placeholder='Search...' />  
          <span class='slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-search slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right'>  
            <lightning-icon icon-name='utility:search' size='xx-Small' class='slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-icon-text-default' aria-hidden='true'></lightning-icon>  
          </span>  
        </div>  

        <template if:true={recordsList}>  
        <div id='listbox-id-2-venu' data-key='dropdownresult' class='slds-show slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-with-icon-7 slds-dropdown_fluid' role='listbox'>  
          <ul class='slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical' role='presentation' >  
            <template if:true={message}>  
            <center>{message}</center>  
            </template>  
            <template for:each={recordsList} for:item='record'>  
              <li id={record.Id} key={record.Id} onclick={onRecordSelection} role='presentation' class='slds-listbox__item'>  
              <div data-key={record.Id} data-name={record.Name} class='slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta' role='option'>  
                <span class='slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon'>  
                  <span class='slds-icon_container'>  
                    <lightning-icon icon-name={iconName} size='small'></lightning-icon>  
                  </span>  
                </span>  
                <span class='slds-media__body'>  
                  <span data-key={record.Id} data-name={record.Name} class='slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity'>{record.Name} </span>  
                </span>  
              </div>  
            </li>  
            </template>  
          </ul>  
        </div>  
        </template>  
        </template>  
      </div>  
    </div>  
  </div>  
</div>
```

JS -

```
   import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import findRecords from '@salesforce/apex/customControllerFSCDocumentSearch.findRecords';

export default class LwcLookupAccount extends LightningElement {
  
@track recordsList;  
  @track searchKey = '';  
  @api selectedValue;  
  @api selectedRecordId;  
  @api objectApiName;  
  @api iconName;  
  @api lookupLabel;  
  @track message;  
    
  onLeave(event) {  
   setTimeout(() => {  
    this.searchKey = '';  
    this.recordsList = null;  
   }, 300);  
  }  
    
  onRecordSelection(event) {  
   this.selectedRecordId = event.target.dataset.key;  
   this.selectedValue = event.target.dataset.name;  
   this.searchKey = '';  
   this.onSeletedRecordUpdate();  
  }  
   
  handleKeyChange(event) {  
   const searchKey = event.target.value;  
   this.searchKey = searchKey;
   if(this.searchKey == ''){
    this.recordsList = [];
   } 
   if(this.searchKey != ''){
    this.getLookupResult();
   }
  } 
   
  removeRecordOnLookup(event) {  
   this.searchKey = '';  
   this.selectedValue = null;  
   this.selectedRecordId = null;  
   this.recordsList = null;  
   this.onSeletedRecordUpdate();  
 }

getLookupResult() { 
    findRecords({ searchKey: this.searchKey, objectName : this.objectApiName })  
        .then((result) => {  
         if (result.length===0) {  
           this.recordsList = [];  
           this.message = 'No Records Found';  
          } else {  
           this.recordsList = result;  
           this.message = '';  
          }  
          this.error = undefined;  
        })  
        .catch((error) => {  
         this.error = error;  
         this.recordsList = undefined;  
        });
    }  
   
  onSeletedRecordUpdate(){ 
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('datapass', { detail: { type: 'selectedAccountId', selectedRecordId: this.selectedRecordId} })); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Issue looks like with the onkeyup event, but when i removed it , results are not displaying as expected

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `handleKeyChange` from two events on the same input element:

- `onkeyup`
- `onchange`

I imagine there's a race condition of sorts.

I'd update your code to only user the `onchange` event.

Comment: Hi Cook-- Thanks for your Answer , is there any alternative for this as to make it like a standard lookup ?

Comment: @Shekher That's a very broad question. Has this resolved the problem with this question?  if so, mark this question as answered.  If you have further questions, post them. Also, look at the base components recipes:  https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/combobox